# Ticket system discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I do command, that if people click on emoji, create ticket.

```
@bot.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
         color = discord.Color.green()
    )
    embed.set_author(name="Откыть запрос")
    embed.add_field(name="To create a ticket react with ", value="help")
    await ctx.send( embed = embed )
    emoji = ''
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await message.add_reaction(emoji=emoji)
```

This is message, where people can click on emoji.

And this is code to create channel:

```
   if str(payload.emoji) == "":
        guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        channel = await guild.create_text_channel('Ticket')
        guild = message.guild
```

If someone can, help please to do that the person who created it and the 3 highest roles would have access to the ticket. And aso that the channel name is from 0000 in order to infinity, or only the name of the one who created the ticket

I know, that few people will help, but I hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
overwrites = {
    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
    payload.member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False)
}
for role in guild.roles[1:4]:
    overwrites[role] = discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True)
channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f"Ticket-{payload.member.display_name}", overwrites=overwrites)
```